# Branch name variable in TFS YAML pipeline

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild

I am trying to make a TFS release YAML pipeline which takes resources from specific builds from branches.

For the resources part:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipelineA
    source: SourceA
    project: ProjectA
  - pipeline: pipelineB
    source: SourceB
    project: projectB
```

This works fine, but it will always release the latest build from pipelineA and pipelineB, regardless which branch it is.
Then I was trying to let it release upon on a specific branch, I tried:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipelineA
    source: SourceA
    project: ProjectA
    branch: task/123_task_name
  - pipeline: pipelineB
    source: SourceB
    project: projectB
```

This works fine as long as there is a build for branch "task/123_task_name".

Now I am trying to let it release upon on the branch I select, I tried:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipelineA
    source: SourceA
    project: ProjectA
    branch: $(Build.SourceBranchName) OR $(Build.SourceBranch) OR task/$(Build.SourceBranchName)
  - pipeline: pipelineB
    source: SourceB
    project: projectB
```

None of them worked, all of them are returning error `The pipeline is not valid. Unable to resolve latest version for pipeline pipelineA. This could be due to inaccessible pipeline or no version is available`.
What should be the correct format for this branch variable, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It because you **can't** put this value in a variable if you're using TFS.

This feature added only to Azure DevOps Services recently:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/pipelines/sprint-212-update

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: Templates
      ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}
```